# DevOps Pipeline NuGet Push - NuGetProtocolVersionNotSupportedException

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

I have had multiple Azure DevOps Pipelines setup and running fine for a long time but I have today discovered they are now failing on the PublishNuGetPackages step. This is the error message.

> VstsNuGetPush.NuGetProtocolVersionNotSupportedException: The supplied
> URL appears to be a NuGet V2 URL. This command only supports the NuGet
> V3 protocol.

The feed in question is a normal Artifacts feed also in Azure DevOps and I can't find any settings anywhere as to which version to use?

The package is generated automatically by the VSBuild task as I have this element in the project file.

`<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>`

Below is the task in the YAML.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Publish NuGet Packages'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isPullRequest, 'false'))
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '{guid}/{guid}'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

This has suddenly started happening on multiple pipelines so I think Microsoft have changed something but I am at a loss how to resolve this. Nothing has changed on my end, and I have checked the existing permissions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struggled with this myself today.  Found this workaround.  Changed the YAML pipeline script to use NuGet.exe 6.5.0:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Install'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.5.0'
```

This link was key: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12595